# The attribute 'DurableClientAttribute' is a WebJobs attribute and not supported in the .NET Worker (Isolated Process)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to create azure durable functions for my project and get the following error for the code below.

```
    [Function("OrdersQueueFunction")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("bpbordersqueue")] [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient orchestrationClient, string orderData, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {orderData}");
        var orderValue = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Order>(orderData);
        await orderService.SaveData(orderValue);

        if (orderValue.Status == Order.OrderStatus.Pending)
        {
            string instanceId = await orchestrationClient.StartNewAsync("OrchestrateRequestApproval", requestMetadata);
            log.LogInformation($"Durable Function Ochestration started: {instanceId}");
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
Error   AZFW0001    The attribute 'DurableClientAttribute' is a WebJobs attribute and not supported in the .NET Worker (Isolated Process).
```

Comment: Change the `Function` to `FunctionName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `[Function("OrdersQueueFunction")]` to `[FunctionName("OrdersQueueFunction")]`.

Install the NuGet package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask`.

When I tried with your code initially even, I got the below error.

[image]

- In namespace section add the `DurableClientAttribute`  as below.

```cs
using DurableClientAttribute = Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.DurableClientAttribute;
```

***My namespaces:***

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using DurableClientAttribute = Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.DurableClientAttribute;
```

Comment: this worked "Change the [Function("OrdersQueueFunction")] to [FunctionName("OrdersQueueFunction")]. ". Please add that as first line, will mark it as answer

Comment: Updated the Answer, Please check once.